# Cronjob to delete all files under 1k in folder & sub directories

Tags: ubuntu, recursion, cron

I'm running this cronjob every hour to delete all files smaller than 1k from the directory **incoming**

```
*/60 * * * * find /usr/incoming/ -size -1k -type f -delete
```

How would I set this up so that it does the same job on all other folders located inside the incoming folder? Recursively I think it's called.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried it out? It should already be doing that recursively.
http://superuser.com/questions/387799/recursively-remove-files-those-size-is-less-than-1mb

Comment: Doh! Yes you're right! I need more coffee ;)